# How can I read B210 GPS sensor while capturing data in gnuRadio

Tags: python, gnuradio, usrp

I am working with a [B210 USRP from Ettus Research](https://www.ettus.com/product/details/UB210-KIT) and for some reason it keeps dropping GPS lock. I would like to periodically poll the GPS lock status and save it to a file while running.

The basic design was generated in gnuradio-companion where the USRP source block is tied to a File Sink block. From there, the python was modified to check the GPS lock from the GPSDO looping on `self.usrp.get_mboard_sensor("gps_locked",0).to_bool()` in the `__init__()` function.

I've added the function below to the class to read GPS data so that I can access it from another process.

```
def getGPS(self,gps_field):
    return self.usrp.get_mboard_sensor(gps_field,0).value
```

When I call the above function from another process, it works the first time through but then produces the following error:

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./experiment.py", line 291, in monitorGPS
    locked = tb.getGPS('gps_locked')
  File "./experiment.py", line 158, in getGPS
    return self.usrp.get_mboard_sensor(gps_field,0).value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnuradio/uhd/uhd_swig.py", line 3493, in get_mboard_sensor
    return _uhd_swig.usrp_sink_sptr_get_mboard_sensor(self, name, mboard)
RuntimeError: ValueError: locked(): unable to determine GPS lock status
```

Is it possible to access GPS information while running a data collect and if so, where am I going wrong here?

-Edit-
It turns out that using threading rather than multiprocessing allows me to access GPS information without error. I would still like to know if there is a better way of going about this.